# rewrite for .htaccess not picking up numbers in the regex

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess, utf-8

I have written a rewrite into the `.htaccess` file so that it replaces any white spaces in the URL with a `.` (dot).

It works fine apart from when there are numbers in the URL.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1.$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]
```

any help would be much appreciated

- `/search/test test` = works with the above regex
- `/search/ 123 123` = does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1.$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]
> ```

The characters `%`, `2` and `0` in the regex character class are seen as 3 literal characters, not a single URL encoded *space* (ie. `%20`). So any numbers containing `2` or `0` that also contain or are followed by a *space* are going to fail since the regex will fail to match. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the %-decoded URL-path, so attempting to match `%20` is not required anyway.

So, you basically just need to remove `%20` from your rule. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\s]*)(?:\s)+(.*)$ $1.$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]
```

Comment: to confirm both this and DLK's version worked but this one solved another issue i had afterwards with special chars in the url - thank you poster